# Cakephp ACL restrict controllers

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

I have cakephp application in which i have two usergroups:

Employee and Client.

As the name suggest employee has is sort of the admins of the applications where the clients is the average user.

Now without going into too much details these two user groups has two different "dashboards views" with different options.

Now to my question:

All of the turtorials ive seen and read about covers how ACL can restrict acess to individual actions. Now my question is how do you set it up so that ACL restict acess to controllers ie. that a client user cannot use nor see any actions in the employee controller?

Also any help i could get setting it up would be nice seeing as ACL seems kinda complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up your permissions correctly, and deny client user access to all actions in Employee controller, client user shouldn't be able to access the controller - without doing any further customization.

```
$this->Acl->deny($group, 'controllers/Posts');
```